# Why cmd give error when we open uiautomatorviewer?

Tags: android-uiautomator

When I run the following command in the command prompt that time I am getting the following error.

Command: `C:\Users\ob>uiautomatorviewer`

Error:

```
-Djava.ext.dirs=..\lib\x86_64;..\lib is not supported.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set your all android path properly.

Add variable in **system environment** as mention below.

**ANDROID_SWT** : C:\Users\chetan\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\lib\x86_64

**ANDROID_HOME** : C:\Users\chetan\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

**ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS** : C:\Users\chetan\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools

Add below mention Path in **Path Variable** in system environment.

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk\bin;

C:\Users\chetan\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin;

C:\Users\chetan\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools;

C:\Users\chetan\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools;

C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin;

C:\Users\chetan\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk;

C:\Users\chetan\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\lib\x86_64\swt.jar;

Answer (score 4):

**Pre-Check** - Verify the java Version installed in your system.
**VERIFY** - `java -version`

> java version "1.8.0_221" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build
>   1.8.0_221-b11) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.221-b11, mixed mode)

If this message appears that means you have **JAVA 8 install** and **uiautomatorviewer** only supports till JAVA 8.

So install JAVA 8 from [here](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) and if you already have JAVA install down grade it to JAVA 8